# Navigating a section in which content displayed varies depending on selected year

Tags: website-design, navigation, dates, placement

I have [a page](http://frc.firstchat.net/scouting) that lists a bunch of events depending on what year is given to the site (current, or via URL):

[image]

The page happens to be at the front of a sub-section, so I have the site's main navigation at the top and another at the right for the page's parent section.

My question is: **Is there a way to do a navigation like that of [24 ways](http://24ways.org/) on the page? And if so, how would it be done?**

Comment: Are you asking how to implement it or what design patterns to follow?

Comment: @Rahul, actually, yes to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I made a list of the years, styled them to be in one row, and hid the overflow by putting the list in a div block with a button on either side to scroll through the list. Using jQuery along with my CSS, I also highlighted the current year and made sure the selected year is visible on page load (as seen in the image @rahul posted above).

Thank you for all your help. It sometimes seems that all one needs to do is just put the question out there and the answer will reveal itself one way or another.